# stop Angular RxJS stopwatch after certain amount of seconds

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm adding a stopwatch feature to my scoreboard timer component (by modifying the countdown clock I had previously). The stopwatch runs continuously, but would like it so that the seconds stop incrementing after 20 seconds (`this.timePerQuestion`).
Please could you see my code below and help me with this issue. Thank you.

```
  stopwatch(): void {
    this.start$ = this.timerService.start$;
    this.reset$ = this.timerService.reset$;
    this.stop$ = this.timerService.stop$;

    this.time$ = concat(this.start$.pipe(first())).pipe(
      switchMapTo(
        timer(0, 1000).pipe(
          scan((acc) => acc + 1, 0)
        )
      ),
      takeUntil(this.stop$.pipe(skip(1))),
      repeatWhen(completeSubj =>
        completeSubj.pipe(
          switchMapTo(
            this.start$.pipe(
              skip(1),
              first()
            )
          )
        )
      )
    ).pipe(tap((value: number) => this.timerService.setElapsed(value)));
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways you can do this: You can make stop$ a subject and emit on it after 20 seconds. The easiest way though is to just stop your timer once it's emitted 20 values. Your timer emits once every second, so if you take(20), your timer will stop after 20 seconds:

```
[....]
switchMapTo(
  timer(0, 1000).pipe(
    scan((acc) => acc + 1, 0),
    take(20) // <- Stops after 20 seconds
  )
),
[....]
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider below approach using `repeatWhen` operator. See [Demo On Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-hplumw)

**timer-service.ts**

```js
  stop$ = new Subject();
  start$ = new Subject();
  questionStarted$ = new BehaviorSubject(true);
  questionLength = 5000; // Change to 20000
  questionLengthSubject$ = new BehaviorSubject(this.questionLength);
  questionLength$ = this.questionLengthSubject$.asObservable();

  stopTimer = () => {
    this.stop$.next();
    this.questionStarted$.next(false);
  };
  startTimer = () => {
    this.start$.next();
    this.questionStarted$.next(true);
  };
  setQuestionLength = questionLength =>
    this.questionLengthSubject$.next(questionLength);

  timer$ = timer(0, 1000).pipe(
    takeUntil(this.stop$),
    repeatWhen(() => this.start$)
  );

  tick$ = combineLatest([this.timer$, this.questionLength$]).pipe(
    tap(([timer, questionLength]) => {
      if (questionLength <= timer * 1000) {
        this.stopTimer();
      }
    }),
    map(([timer, questionLength]) => questionLength / 1000 - timer)
  );
```

**app.component.ts**

```js
  tick$ = this.timerService.tick$;
  questionStarted$ = this.timerService.questionStarted$;
  startTimer = this.timerService.startTimer;
  stopTimer = this.timerService.stopTimer
  constructor (private timerService: TimerService) {}
```

Comment: Thanks! I will try to use the repeatWhen operator in my code and let you know if I have any questions.

Comment: It looks like I need to replace the repeatWhen in my code in the stopwatch, not sure what  the code should look like. I've included my Stackblitz in my post above.

Comment: I have just gone through the app. Your stop watch seems to be working as expected

Comment: Yes if you toggle down to the stopwatch timer you can see that it is working but I need it to stop at this.timePerQuestion, otherwise the clock runs continuously and doesn't stop.